# Call a Sproc on another SQL Server without being linked via TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I want to call a sproc on server B from server A in TSQL without linking the servers.  Is it possible to use something like a connection string to execute this sproc?  The return will be a single nvarchar value.

Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid "linked servers", you'd normally use [OPENDATASOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx)

After comment:

```
EXEC OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI', 'Data Source=London\Payroll;Integrated Security=SSPI').remoteDB.remoteSchema.remoteProc @param1, @param2,...
```

Simple 4 part naming convention. The whole OPENDATASOURCE simply replaces the linked server name...

Note: you may have issues with "[adhoc access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187873.aspx)"

Comment: +1 but there should be a triple bonus score if you can provide an example of it using a sproc, since msdn doesn't give one

Comment: wow weirdness, i can't upvote you again, my click-happy fingers managed to unclick my vote & i can't vote up again.. wow. that sucks!

Answer (score 0):

i know of no way of doing it without ...

1. creating an extended stored proc to do it for you
2. perhaps using xp_cmdshell to use isql to execute your stored proc .. however, getting the result might be tricky (perhaps write the result to a table on your current server in the same sql file that isql is reading)

-don